# Importing Javascript in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, if-statement

I've got the following HTML and Javascript:

```
<noscript>
    <div id="player">
    <h2>Warning! You should enable your JavaScript!</h2>
    </div>
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var videoSource="<?php echo $fileName;?>";
    createPlayer(videoSource);
</script>
```

I need the import this block of code here in the if:

```
<?php
 if($media[$id] != null){
        $video = $media[$id];
        $fileName = "folder/".$video;
       //Here
    }else{
        echo("Error !");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily close php tags, insert html code and then reopen php tags just like that:

```
<?php
if($media[$id] != null){
    $video = $media[$id];
    $fileName = "folder/".$video;
?>
<noscript>
    <div id="player">
        <h2>Warning! You should enable your JavaScript!</h2>
    </div>
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var videoSource="<?php echo $fileName;?>";
    createPlayer(videoSource);
</script>
<?php
    }else{
        echo("Error !");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what your asking:

```
<?php
 if($media[$id] != null){
        $video = $media[$id];
        $fileName = "folder/".$video;
?>
  ... html ...
<?
    }else{
        echo("Error !");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hopefully [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) has been enabled. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your javascript in `?>` and `<?php` within the PHP if statement and you'll be good.

The joy of PHP is you can go from PHP to HTML over and over.

```
<?php
 if($media[$id] != null){
        $video = $media[$id];
        $fileName = "folder/".$video;
?>
<noscript>
    <div id="player">
    <h2>Warning! You should enable your JavaScript!</h2>
    </div>
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var videoSource="<?php echo $fileName;?>";
    createPlayer(videoSource);
</script>
<?php
    }else{
        echo("Error !");
    }
?>
```

Think of anything from the start of a PHP file to the first `<?php`, the last `?>` to the end of the file, or anything between `?>` and `<?php` as an implicit php **echo** call with that content.